# How does moduleNameMapper work for mocking a npm module?

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I am using Jest to test, and the test is failing due to parsing problems inside a npm package I am using, since it is not plain JavaScript. However, they are saying in the error that I can use moduleNameMapper. I do not understand the documentation on how this works. Can someone tell me how to target my npm module?

Lets say that I have several imports to my npm mobule

```
import 'my-module/something-A';
import 'my-module/something-A/somethingB';
import 'my-module/something-A/somethingB/somethingC';
```

I would think it is best to add all of these three inside a regex:

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^my-module*$": "<rootDir>/my-stubbed-module-in-a-file.js"
     }
  }
}
```

I Have two question regarding this:

1) How to target all the tree imports of my module in this part of the package.json `"^my-module*$"` ?

2) What should be inside the file of `"<rootDir>/my-stubbed-module-in-a-file.js"`?

Resouce to moduleNameMapper: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string

Comment: 1) Instead of going for a regexp solution immediately, have you managed to get it working when hard coding each individual module?

2) How are you importing the modules in your own code? e.g.  `import x from 'my-module'?